# can't find my devices list in xcode managed profile

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created a development certificate in apple developers account ..

[image]

and as you can see there is 63 devices included ..

but in xcode am not able to see available devices ...

[image]

why and how to solve this?

Comment: those 2 are different provisioning profiles. One which you are looking in Xcode is Auto generated, not the one which you created on Portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the provisioning profile in **textEditor** you can see the **UDID** of devices that are included in it. I don't think you can see that in Xcode.

Search of key "***ProvisionedDevices***" after opening it in textEditor

Comment: I don't see a list but usually there is a number of the available number of devices in the profile

Comment: cause am trying to distribute using fabric but i don't see any of my registered devices

Comment: You can find the full list (independent of project) of provisioning profile here:-~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning.